# How do I make my radio buttons work with if statements for calculations?

Tags: php, if-statement, radio-button

so for a class assignment we are using HTML and PHP to make a form that asks a user to input two (2) numbers and to choose between addition, subtraction, multiplication or division form using radio buttons, THEN to input a guess as to what the answer is. Our assignment is to echo out to the user specifying whether or not their answer is correct or not.

The part where I am having troubles is in the "if" and "else" statements. For example, if I choose 1 and 2 as my numbers, guess 3 and choose addition as my method of calculation, I not only get echoed out "Congratulations! You choose the correct answer of 3!" but i also get my else statements from division, subtraction, and multiplication specifying that I did it incorrectly.

Here's my Code:(keep in mind-- the birthday function has yet to be made.)
Also, I'm having difficulties regarding my form validation -- making it so that the user has in fact entered the required fields.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Howdy</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>PHP_SELF</h1>

<?php


//process the form if the submit button was pressed
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//form validation goes here


/////////////////////////////////////////VARIABLES ARE BEING MADE HERE
//simplify the form variables
//later on we will do this in form validation

//create a variable called firstname and store in it
//the value from the POST array for firstname from the form
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];

//creating variables for num1 and num2 that user inputed
$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$num2 = $_POST['num2'];

//creating a variable called sum
//this is for when the user chooses to ADD 
//num1 and num2
$sum = $num1 + $num2;

//creating a variable called difference
//this is for when the user chooses to SUBTRACT
//num1 and num2
$difference = $num1 - $num2;

//creating a variable called product
//this is for when the user chooses to MULTIPLY
//num1 and num2
$product  = $num1 * $num2;

//creating a variable called quotient
//this is for when the user chooses to DIVIDE
//num1 and num2
$quotient = $num1 / $num2;

//creating a variable called guess and store it in the
//value from the POST array for the guess from the form
$guess = $_POST['guess'];

//creating a variable called birthday and store it in the
//value from the POST array for the user's birthday
$birthday = $_POST['birthday'];



if ($sum == $guess) {

echo "<p>Congratulations $firstname. You answered correctly with $guess.<p>\n";

} else if ($sum != $guess){

echo "<p>$firstname, you answered incorrectly. The correct answer is $sum.</p>\n";

} 


if ($difference == $guess) {

echo "<p>Congratulations $firstname. You answered correctly with $guess.<p>\n";

} else if ($difference != $guess){

echo "<p>$firstname, you answered incorrectly. The correct answer is $difference.</p>\n";

} 


if ($product == $guess) {

echo "<p>Congratulations $firstname. You answered correctly with $guess.<p>\n";

} else if ($product != $guess){

echo "<p>$firstname, you answered incorrectly. The correct answer is $product.</p>\n";

}       



if ($quotient == $guess) {

echo "<p>Congratulations $firstname. You answered correctly with $guess.<p>\n";

} else if ($quotient != $guess){

echo "<p>$firstname, you answered incorrectly. The correct answer is $quotient.</p>\n";

} 


} //end of the isset submit conditional statement


//show the form if it is the user's first time her OR if any of the required forms are missing

if(!isset($_POST ['submit']) OR empty($firstname) OR empty($num1) OR empty($num2)) { ?>

<h2>Please fill out the following: </h2>



<!--FORM BEGINS-->
<form action= "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<p><label for="firstname">Please enter your first name: </label>
<input id="firstname" type="text" size="30" name="firstname" value="<?php if(isset($firstname)) echo $firstname; ?>"/><p>

<!--Challenge Dealio-->
<p><label for="Num1">Please enter a number: </label>
<input id="Num1" type="number" size="30" name="num1" value="<?php if(isset($num1)) echo $num1; ?>" /></p>

<p><label for="Num2">Please enter another number: </label>
<input id="Num2" type="number" size="30" name="num2" value="<?php if(isset($num2)) echo $num2; ?>"/><p>

<p>Please choose one of the following: </p>
<p>
    <input name="add" id="answer" type="radio" value="add" />Add<br />
    <input name="subtract" id="answer" type="radio" value="subtract" />Subtract<br />
    <input name="multiply" id="answer" type="radio" value="multiply" />Multiply<br />
    <input name="divide" id="answer" type="radio" value="divide" />Divide<br />
</p>  

<p><label for="guess">Please put in a guess for the answer: </label>
<input id="guess" type="number" size="30" name="guess" value="<?php if(isset($guess)) echo $guess; ?>"/></p>

<p><label for="birthday">Please enter your birth date: </label>
<input id="birthday" type="date" size="30" name="birthday" value="<?php if(isset($birthday)) echo $birthday; ?>"/></p>

<!--Submit Button-->
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>

<?php
} //end form conditional statement
?>



</body>
</html>




What did I do wrong? And how can I go about fixing this?
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all al radio buttons should have same name with different value. And in same page you cannot have same id's

```
 <p>
     <input name="action" id="add" type="radio" value="add" />Add<br />
     <input name="action" id="subtract" type="radio" value="subtract" />Subtract<br />
     <input name="action" id="multiply" type="radio" value="multiply" />Multiply<br />
     <input name="action" id="divide" type="radio" value="divide" />Divide<br />
 </p>
```

Then in your php to perform selected option,

```
 if($_POST['action'] == "add") {
     $result = $num1 + $num2;
 } else if($_POST['action'] == "subtract") {
     $result = $num1 - $num2;
 } else if($_POST['action'] == "multiply") {
     $result  = $num1 * $num2;
 } else if($_POST['action'] == "divide") {
     $result = $num1 / $num2;
 }
```

Rename all values to `$result`.

```
 if($result == $guess) {
      echo "<p>Congratulations $firstname. You answered correctly with $guess.<p>\n";
 } else {
      echo "<p>$firstname, you answered incorrectly. The correct answer is $difference.</p>\n";

}
```

No need to check so many times, take the result to 1 variable, check it only once.

**Edit**: For birthday part
In View

```
<select name="year">add options here</select>
<select name="month">add options here</select>
<select name="day">add options here</select>
```

In PHP,

```
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$day = $_POST['day'];

$date = $year ."-". $month ."-".$day;

$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));

if(date('m-d') == date('m-d', $date)) {
    // today is users birthday. show any message you want here.
 }
```

Comment: Okay great. Now how would I go about echoing out to the user if their guess was incorrect? Is it more or less the same?

Comment: Thank you a bunch! This helped me out a lot! If you don't mind, I may have more questions in a bit! :)

Comment: if answer was helpful, please accept it. accept the answer.

Comment: @WalkinDeadGirll You can ask any doubts in answer, i ll help you

Comment: this is regarding my birthday function thing... I'm a bit stuck as to where to start with this.         """ Also ask them to enter their birthdate.
Use three drop-down lists in your form to allow the user to select the month, date and year of their birth date. An array should be used for the month and each of these lists will require the use of a loop to place the values into a drop down list.
If a user goes to your site on their birth date, they should see a 'special message'."""

Comment: instead of separate dropdown try using some date pickers. where user can select his birth date.

Comment: unfortunately it has to be separate drop down lists

Comment: no problem i ll alter my answer, please check in some time.

Comment: @WalkinDeadGirll check the answer.

Comment: Ok, so i'm supposed to use arrays with the years, months, and days, how would I go about doing this? arrays have always confused me.

Comment: What is the issue you are getting??

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot have the same ids on your radios. They must be different with the same name.

```
<p>
   <input name="action" id="add" type="radio" value="add" />Add<br />
   <input name="action" id="subtract" type="radio" value="subtract" />Subtract<br />
   <input name="action" id="multiply" type="radio" value="multiply" />Multiply<br />
   <input name="action" id="divide" type="radio" value="divide" />Divide<br />
</p>
```

Then you are not validating which function the user is choosing via the checkboxes. You are iterating through all the `if`and `else`without filtering which function was chosen.

What I would do is use a Switch Case statement to filter which method of calculation was chosen and then compare if the guess is right. Something like:

```
switch $answer {
                case "add":
                //Check if guess is right and echo
                break;
                case "substract":
                //Check if guess is right and echo
                break;
                case "multiply":
                //Check if guess is right and echo
                break; 
                case "divide":
                //Check if guess is right and echo
                break;
              };
```

If you are not allowed to use the Switch Case Statement then you should first check which answer was marked and then if the guess is right:

```
if($answer == "add"){
   if($sum == $guess){
      echo "Congrats";
   } else {
      echo "error";
   }
} else if($answer == "substract"){
   if($difference == $guess){
      echo "Congrats";
   } else {
      echo "error";
   }
} else if($answer == "multiply"){
   if($product == $guess){
      echo "Congrats";
   } else {
      echo "error";
   }
} else if($answer == "divide"){
   if($quotient == $guess){
      echo "Congrats";
   } else {
      echo "error";
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.